# Kafka create topic on AWS cluster time-out

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka

I am trying to connect to an amazon managed streaming kafka cluster. I've been following the tutorial on creating a topic https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/create-topic.html.

My VPC security group for this cluster allows for any traffic inbound and outbound, so I don't suspect this is preventing the connection.

I've tried this command.

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper ZookeeperConnectString --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic AWSKafkaTutorialTopic
```

Which produces the offending error:

```
Exception in thread "main" kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:242)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:238)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:96)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1825)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$ZookeeperTopicService$.apply(TopicCommand.scala:262)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:53)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

What am I doing wrong and what configuration is needed to prevent the connection from timing out?

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=297702 This post on Amazon Web Services should help.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error. Once your cluster is active, go to MSK service and check the security group for the cluster. Then you have to add the inbound rule in that security group to allow all traffic coming from the security group of your client machine.

It's the last point in the tutorial:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/create-client-machine.html

Comment: I did this to all of my rules (they each allow all traffic from their respective sg's) but I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion - if you are not using TLS and are following [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/create-topic.html), make sure that when you are connecting to your cluster, you are using the `ZookeeperConnectString` (using port 2181) that is returned by the `describe-cluster` method, and not `ZookeeperConnectStringTls` (which is using port 2182)